# Noun for 'late comings'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

For an application I'm working on I need to log whenever a student is late. I'm having trouble finding a noun to use as the title of the collection of these occurrences.

As an example:

- When a student registers to the school you would save the record in a collection of *registrations*
- When a student misses or skips a class you would save the record in a collection of *absences*

When a student is late to class you would save the record in a collection of ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... in a collection of **[latenesses](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lateness)** or **[tardinesses](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tardiness)**, or (partial) absences (since they were absent for part of the class).

Comment: +1 for the notion of "tardy," but to save space and avoid the somewhat awkward use of the plural of "tardiness," you could also consider "a collection of **tardies,**" [the plural of "tardy" as a noun](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/is-there-a-plural-of-tardy). cc: @JiriKrewinkel

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lateness) does not license 'latenesses', giving only the mass noun usage. Similarly, ODO does not license a count noun usage of 'tardiness' (and so does not license 'a collection/list of tardinesses).

Answer (score 1):

In a collection of "late arrivals" or "late attendees" should suffice.

Comment: Can you provide support for your suggestions? We prefer answers to be longer, with information (like definitions) and links to support his/her suggestions. Doing this may cause your answer to avoid being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**[latecomer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/latecomer)** (noun), Plural **latecomers**

> A person who arrives late.
>
> ‘latecomers were not admitted before the interval’

Comment: These are the people that are late. Not the instances themselves.